# Changing Array size inside a loop causing Error in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I am trying to dynamically set the size of array and store some value in it but it is causing an error.

here is the code,

```
syms k
x=[1 0 0 1];
y=[];
for b=1:4
    step1= x(b)*exp(-2*pi*1i*k*((b-1)/length(x)));
    y(b)=step1
end
```

what i am trying to do is to store each value of step1 in the array 'y'.

and here is the error,

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.
Error in Untitled3 (line 6)
    y(K)=1/exp((pi*k*3*1i)/2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, Matlab struggles to go from double to symbolic, so you should make it clear from the get-go that y is to contain symbolic elements:

```
syms k y
x=[1 0 0 1];
for K=1:4
    step1= x(K)*exp(-2*pi*1i*k*((K-1)/length(x)));
    y(K)=step1
end
```

Comment: why do i need to go to symbolic ? is it because there is symbol 'k' in the term ?

Comment: exactly, when you put the k in y, it becomes symbolic (syms)

Comment: although it works but its not a good way, the program runs fine but the error remain in the code ,
what is the way of pre-allocating the memory with sym variable and pre-defined array size ?

Comment: look, when i write this y = sym(zeros(1,N)) the program shows the incorrect answer and if i don't write this the answer is correct but as soon as i replace my program into the function and call that function then it shows the incorrect answer, could u invite me to chat so i can show u the code

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using a symbolic variable `k` and a loop counter `K`?  It looks like you are confusing the two.  I think this is what you are trying to implement:

```
x=[1 0 0 1];
y=[];

for k=1:4
    y(k)= x(k)*exp(-2i*pi*k*((k-1)/length(x)));    
end
```

Note: When working with large loops, it is much faster for MATLAB to pre-allocate the array rather than dynamically resizing it.  For example by changing `y=[];` to `y=zeros(1,4);`

Comment: already did that pre-allocate memory thing , it didn't work
btw k and K were two different variables i have now replaced small 'k' by 'b' to avoid confusion